# Update of ESLint gives the following error: imported multiple times import/no-duplicates

Tags: typescript, eslint, date-fns

Updating ESLint to 6.6.0 is giving the following error :

> error  '/node_modules/date-fns/typings.d.ts'  imported multiple times
>
> import/no-duplicates

Code:

```js
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import getTime from 'date-fns/get_time';
import isValid from 'date-fns/is_valid';
```

date-fns version : 2.4.1

How can I fix the same. Thank you

Comment: According to your answer, it seems that you imported the module multiple times. Please make sure to read the error messages before posting them on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed by consolidating the imports from date-fns into a single import. Thank you.

```js
import {format, getTime, isValid} from 'date-fns';
```